# Retain primary keys in event rows needs to be restored

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, database-restore

I have an SQL database with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships. Most of the relationships are based on an auto increment field "ID."  In some cases when rows from tables are deleted, I export all the data from multiple tables to XML files before deleting the data from the database in the event that this data should need restoring at a later date.

How will the database IDs be treated?  Can I simply restore the data into the existing database and the Ids and relationships will remain intact?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-insert the data, even into an IDENTITY field, provided you use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table] ON`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable ON

INSERT INTO
  yourTable (
    id,
    field1,
    field2
  )
SELECT
  id,
  field1,
  field2
FROM
  yourBackup

SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable OFF
```

Note that you must specify *all* of the fields, including the ID, in the INSERT statement.

Once you've re-created the records with the primary keys, then you can re-create the records in tables that use them as foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes. There is a flag in SQL Server, set against each table, that indicates if specifying a value for an identity column is allowed or not. By default it is switched off. You'll need to temporarily enable it when re-inserting your data:

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Name varchar(20) = 'Dave'


INSERT INTO Example(Name) VALUES(@Name)

SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

DELETE FROM Example WHERE Id = @Id


SET IDENTITY_INSERT Example ON

INSERT INTO Example(Id, Name) VALUES(@Id, @Name)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Example OFF
```

Note that in order to satisfy any foreign key relationship you'll need to re-insert the data into the 'one' table before the 'many' table.